# How do I create the below nested if logical flow formula for Google Sheets

Tags: excel, if-statement, google-sheets, nested

I have 6 data entry columns and 1 column called current status (where I want the data of the most recent entry to be).

What I am looking to achieve is something of the following

```
"IF O2 is BLANK return T2, otherwise return 02;
IF T2 is BLANK return Y2, otherwise return T2;
IF Y2 is BLANK return AD2, otherwise return Y2;
IF AD2 is BLANK return AI2, otherwise return AD2;
IF AI2 is BLANK return AN2, otherwise return AI2;"
```

Using the sheet, it would be filled out in chronological order over time (first cell AN2, then AI2, then AD2, then Y2, then T2, then 02. However, I want the current status column to show the most recent entry.

This is the formula I have tried to use.

=IF(O2="",T2,IF(T2="",Y2,IF(Y2="",AD2,IF(AD2="",AI2,IF(AI2="",AN2,O2)))))

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

You want to use ISBLANK() inside the IF items:

```
=IF(ISBLANK(O2), T2, IF(ISBLANK(T2), Y2, IF(ISBLANK(Y2), AD2, IF(ISBLANK(AD2), AI2, IF(ISBLANK(AI2), AN2, "02")))))
```

Note that you have zero two as the last item, so I put hat in quotes.